# How can I toggle a specific value in React

Tags: reactjs

*I'm creating a movie App, I display each movie as a card with an image, title, and Overview, I've created a button to toggle the overview text with showLess and Showmore when I click on the button. The problem is when I clicked on ShowMore to get the rest of the overview, it applied to all the cards. but what I want is when I click on showmore I want to toggle just this specific card.*

**Card Components**

```
const MovieCard = ({moviesList}) => {
    const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);
    return (
       moviesList.map((singleMovie)=> {
           const {id , title, poster_path, overview} = singleMovie;
            return (
               <article key={id} className="card">
                   <img src={`${ImgPath}` + poster_path} alt={title}/>
                   <h1>{title}</h1>
                   <p>{readMore ? overview :`${overview.substring(0,50)}...`}
                    <button onClick={()=> setReadMore(!readMore)}>
                     {readMore ? "ShowLess" : "ShowMore" }
                    </button>
                   </p>
               </article>
            )
       })
    )
}

export default MovieCard
```

*What do you think?*

Comment: You can't have n movies and expect 1 single boolean to control them individually.

Comment: In this case all buttons will apply with the !readMore text..so you have to make a state for each different singleMovie for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **useRef** hook, in this case to access the DOM node directly. With useRef you can create a mutable value that exists for the lifetime of the component instance. Then, you use **yourRef.current** to access or update the mutable value.
All React components can be passed a ref using the ref prop, in which React will automatically assign the instance of the component to **yourRef.current**.